# how to retrieve data through ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want a user to input a country, then it will output its population. My javascript is suppose to look up the country that the user input when the button is clicked, then goes through the PHP file and gets the country's population.

my HTML is:

```
  <label>
    Country:
      <input name="country" type="text" id="country"></label>
      <input type="button" value="Find population" id="findPop">
  <p id="output"></p
```

and javascript:

```
var countryFound = function(data) {
    var theCountry = $("#country").val();
    var population = data["country"];
    if (data["country"])
    {
        $("#output").html(theCountry + " population is " + population);
    }
    else {
        $("#output").html(theCountry + " is not found");
    }
};

$("#findPop").click(function(){
    var theCountry = $("#country").val();
    $("#output").html("Loading...");
    $.getJSON("countrylookup.php", "country="+theCountry , countryFound);  
});
```

my PHP code is:

```
if (isset($_GET['country'])) { // get the parameters country
    $column = 'country';
    $value = $_GET['country'];
else {
    print -1; // an error code
    return; 
}

$data = array( 'country'=>'Peru', 'capital'=>'Lima', 'area'=>'1285220', 'population'=>'29907003', 'continent'=>'South America' ),
array( 'country'=>'Philippines', 'capital'=>'Manila', 'area'=>'300000', 'population'=>'99900177', 'continent'=>'Asia' );
function findData ( $whichColumn, $data, $searchValue)
{
    $result = array();
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        if ($row[$whichColumn] == $searchValue)
            $result[] = $row;
    }
    return $result;
}

print json_encode ( findData($column, $data, $value) );
```

but for some reason, when I input Peru as the country, it says `Peru is not found`. Am I not retrieving the correct data from the php or what? I'm pretty sure that my php code is correct.

Comment: I just can bear this? Nobody seems to suggest the obvious? Your `$data` variable has two arrays seperated by a comma, which is just a syntax error and wont work at all ?

Comment: don't think that's a problem.

Comment: It most certainly is, you can't assign two arrays to a single variable. I tested your code and sorted out the errors, and posted an answer below that I've tested and seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it :

```
$(function() {
  $("#findPop").on('click', function(){
    var theCountry = $("#country").val();
    $("#output").html("Loading...");
    $.getJSON("countrylookup.php", {country: theCountry}, function(data) {
       var population = data[0] != "false" ? data.population : false,
           msg = population ? (" population is " + population) : " is not found";
       $("#output").html(theCountry + msg);
    });
  });
});
```

PHP

```
$value = isset($_GET['country']) ? strtolower(trim($_GET['country'])) : false;
$result = false;

if ($value) {
    $data = array(
          'peru' => array(
                          'capital'=>'Lima',
                          'area'=>'1285220',
                          'population'=>'29907003',
                          'continent'=>
                          'South America'
                    ),
    'philippines' => array(
                          'capital'=>'Manila',
                          'area'=>'300000',
                          'population'=>'99900177',
                          'continent'=>'Asia'
                    )
    );
    if (array_key_exists($value, $data)) $result = $data[$value];
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

For the jQuery side, I recommend using the [.get() function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).

```
$("#findPop").click(function(){
    var theCountry = $("#country").val();
    $("#output").html("Loading...");
    $.get("countrylookup.php", function(data) {
        if(data) {
            // Do whatever you want to do with the data, e.g.:
            var population = data.population,
                theCountry = $("#country").val();

            // Do more magic
            $("#output").html(theCountry = " population is " + population)
        } else {
            // Error handling
        }
    });  
});
```

Comment: This is all very good advice, but the OP is already using json_encode(), so that's not the problem, and the success key has nothing to do with the problem at hand? An answer that solved the issue would probably be more appropriate !

Comment: @adeneo The problem is that the key used in the array later encoded in the JSON format can be misleading, so I am helping to clear things up. And if I am placed in a similar situation I would recommend using a success key as well - I don't see why is that irrelevant (any recommendation/help goes a long way, no?)

Comment: for some reason, when I edited my javascript to your codes, the population is undefined.

Comment: Maybe you can try checking the JSON object that your PHP script is outputting? The key to population may not be 'data.population'.

Answer (score 0):

There is a } missing before the else in the fourth line of the PHP code.